# How to create a bar chart in which the y-axis is expressed in percents?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

Suppose there is a chart like the following:
[image: Example of a chart]

This chart was created using the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar,
enlargelimits=0.15,
symbolic x coords={Category 1,Category 2,Category 3},
xtick=data,
nodes near coords,
]
\addplot coordinates {(Category 1,6) (Category 2,2) (Category 3,3.5)};
\addplot coordinates {(Category 2,2) (Category 3,2.5)};
\addplot coordinates {(Category 3,4)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I was wondering if it is possible to modify this chart in pgfplots in 
such a way that the y-axis expresses percents. So in this case, the blue 
bar in Category 1 would go up to 100%; the blue bar and the red bar in 
Category 2 would go up to 50% each; the blue bar, the red bar, and the 
brown bar in Category 3 would go up to 35%, 25%, and 40% respectively. 
(In other words, it is assumed that in each Category, the combined 
values of the bars amount to 100%.) At the same time, I would like to 
keep the non-percentage values in the label over the bars and mark only these values (6 in Cat. 1; 2 and 2 in Cat. 2 etc.) or combine them with percentages (6, 100% in Cat. 1; 2, 50% and 2, 50% in Cat. 2 etc.).

In short, my question is: how to do that in pgfplots? (And, if that is not possible, then perhaps straight in PGF/TikZ.)

EDIT: Obviously, you can achieve this manually in pgfplots by calculating the percentages, then writing them like `(Category 1,100)`, then providing the y-axis with an appropriate description (e.g. “in percents”), and then changing the label of each bar so that it shows the non-percentage values. What I'm looking for, however, is a little bit more automated solution :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For things like this, I would always provide the data in the form of a `pgfplotstable` (which requires the package of the same name to be loaded). You can create a table using something like

```
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=false]{
Category 1,6,0,0
Category 2,2,2,0
Category 3,3.5,2.5,4
}\data
```

The table is then available as `\data`.

You can then add a new column `sum` that contains the sum for each row, using

```
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
    create col/expr={
        \thisrow{1} + \thisrow{2} + \thisrow{3}
    }
]{sum}{\data}
```

You can then scale the data while you plot it, using

```
 \addplot table [y expr=\thisrow{1}/\thisrow{sum}*100,meta=1] {\data};
```

which specifies that the data point should be divided by the `sum` entry in the current row and multiplied by 100, while the label (the `meta` value) should still come from the unchanged column (column 1 in this case).

You can wrap this into a more comfortable style, so that you only have to call

```
\addplot table [percentage series=1] {\data};
```

to add a plot.

**Edit:** To print the original values and the percentages above the bars, you can use the argument to `nodes near coords={...}`. Since you're going to print two different variables, but only one is available as `\pgfplotspointmeta`, you need to make the other available using `visualization depends on=<value> \as \<macro>`. Unfortunately, this doesn't work if you delete some points using `restrict y to domain=...` or `y filter` (this looks like a bug, I'll look into what can be done about this). So in order to still only show the bars with nonzero values, one workaround is to draw the axis on top of the chart (otherwise you'd see thin lines where the zero bars are), and make the `nodes near coords` code check whether the values are larger than zero.

[image]

Here's the complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=false]{
Category 1,6,0,0
Category 2,2,2,0
Category 3,3.5,2.5,4
}\data

\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
    create col/expr={
        \thisrow{1} + \thisrow{2} + \thisrow{3}
    }
]{sum}{\data}

\pgfplotsset{
    percentage plot/.style={
        point meta=explicit,
    every node near coord/.append style={
        align=center,
        text width=1cm
    },
        nodes near coords={
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\iszero{\originalvalue==0}
        \ifnum\iszero=0
            \pgfmathprintnumber{\originalvalue}$\,\%$\\ \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed zerofill,precision=1]{\pgfplotspointmeta}
        \fi},
    nodes near coords align=vertical,
        yticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\,$\%$,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=100,
        enlarge y limits={upper,value=0.18},
    visualization depends on={y \as \originalvalue}
    },
    percentage series/.style={
        table/y expr=\thisrow{#1}/\thisrow{sum}*100,table/meta=#1
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis on top,
    width=10cm,
    percentage plot,ybar,bar width=0.75cm,
    enlarge x limits=0.25,
    symbolic x coords={Category 1,Category 2,Category 3},
    xtick=data
]
\addplot table [percentage series=1] {\data};
\addplot table [percentage series=2] {\data};
\addplot table [percentage series=3] {\data};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your answer is brilliant: it's extensive and lucid, and it does precisely what I asked about. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, and I must say that I thought once I got this code, I could easily change the bar labels to express both values (something like “6, 100%” for Category 1), but I'm actually struggling to do this (still have a lot to learn, obviously). Could you help me out with any suggestions? :)

Comment: @jemp: The solution is not quite as straightforward as one might anticipate. I've adapted my code now.

Comment: So which part exactly does the modification of the `ylabel` from a regular value like `10` to the one expressed with a percent sign like `10%`?

Comment: @drozzy: The line `\pgfmathprintnumber{\originalvalue}$\,\%$`. `\originalvalue` is the `10`, then there's a thin space, and then the escaped `\%` sign. The code immediately surrounding it checks whether the value of the datapoint is zero, and only prints a label if it's not.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't find the command `\originalvalue` anywhere in the pgfplots manual. How did you find out about it?

Comment: P.S.: Btw, I am asking about ticks, not nodes on top of bars.

Comment: This worked for me: `yticklabel={$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}$\%},`

Comment: @drozzy: Ah yes, sorry, I misunderstood what you were asking. You're right, that's the line you need. Although technically there should be a thin space (`\,`) between the number and the `%`.

Comment: +1 for the `yticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\,$\%$,`