# Is it possible to create a bar chart with confidence intervals?

Tags: pgfplots

Is it possible to build a chart like in this older question but to add confidence intervals?

[How to create a bar chart in which the y-axis is expressed in percents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26496/how-to-create-a-bar-chart-in-which-the-y-axis-is-expressed-in-percents)

Comment: Welcome at tex.stackexchange!

Comment: Sounds a lot like what pgfplots calls `error bars`... ? These are available for bar plots as well. Details are in http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf and there are also a couple of related questions here which involve both bars and error bars.

Comment: @Scott I think an example would be good. You could draw it on paper and see if anybody knows how to do it with TeX.

Comment: An example would help tremendously.